# Create Rows from split array data

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table which looks like the example i have provided below with this data
Table

```
     T     som     da     pap
    ------------------------------
    A  | soma | label | nami    |
    ----------------------------
    B  | a:b  | acha  | wen:nda |
    -----------------------------
    C  |  d   |  k    | nd:ke   |
    -----------------------------
```

Using the data in javascript/jquery i would like to 
  create a table like this based on count of pap

```
     T     som     da     pap
    ------------------------------
    A  | soma | label | nami    |
    ----------------------------
    B  |  a  | acha  | wen     |
    -----------------------------
    B  |  b  | acha  | nda     |
    -----------------------------
    C  | d   |   k   | nd      |
    -----------------------------
    C  | d   |   k   | ke     |
    -----------------------------
```

Suggestions, I have tried but so far the double data i can only put in td instead of tr

Comment: Will there always be the same number of items in `som` and `pap`? If not, what should happen if they have different numbers?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there are always the same number of items in both cells.

```
$("#tableID tr").each(function() {
    var som = $(this).find("td:eq(1)").text();
    var som_array = som.split(':');
    if (som_array.length > 1) {
        var pap_array = $(this).find("td:eq(3)").text().split(':');
        $.each(som_array, function(i, som_el) {
            var pap_el = pap_array[i];
            var new_row = $(this).clone();
            new_row.eq(1).text(som_el);
            new_row.eq(3).text(pap_el);
            $(this).after(new_row);
        }
        $(this).remove();
    }
});
```

This loops over all the rows in the table, and checks whether the `som` column contains multiple items. If it does, it split it up, and also splits up the `pap` column. Then it loops over these values, makes a copy of the original row, and replaces those columns with the elements of the split strings. Finally it removes the original row.